# How can i paginate an array of a document using node and mongoose or mongo?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f0083848f162b38900dc113"),
    "isEmailVerified" : false,
    "isProfileSetup" : true,
    "my_events" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f005a63b5524eb74813de11"), 
        ObjectId("5f005a5bb5524eb74813de0c"), 
        ObjectId("5f017dfcf8e6d8615cddfd6f")
    ]
}
```

I have this document in user's collection and i am trying to paginate the array my_events only. I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

Firstly is this possible to paginate this array without event fetching it completely from the db and if yes please share the way here.

```
{{url_local}}/api/event?user_id=5f0083848f162b38900dc113&page=1&limit=2
```

Above call should find the user with mentioned user_id and should return only these values :-

```
ObjectId("5f005a63b5524eb74813de11"),
ObjectId("5f005a5bb5524eb74813de0c")
```

And,

```
{{url_local}}/api/event?user_id=5f0083848f162b38900dc113&page=2&limit=2
```

it should return this :-

```
ObjectId("5f017dfcf8e6d8615cddfd6f")
```

Comment: check out the [`$slice` projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) and [`$slice` aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with aggregation in MongoDB, pls check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/

But in general, the advantage of paging will be lost as aggregations are heavy on the database, you should consider to change the document structure and create a collection for subdocuments and add a reference to your parent document if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this resolved my problem for now.